# Can the intersection of two non-commensurable lattices be Zariski-dense?

Tags: lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be lattices of a simple non-compact Lie group $G$. Suppose that $\Gamma_1\cap\Gamma_2$ is Zariski-dense in $G$. Can we conclude that $\Gamma_1\cap\Gamma_2$ is also a lattice?

For instance, if one consider the following lattices of $\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$: $$\operatorname{SU}(I_3,\sigma;\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])=\{M\in\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])\mid\sigma(M)^\top M=I_3\}$$ where $d\in\mathbb{N}$ is square-free and $\sigma$ is the non-trivial involution of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Their intersection is always finite. With suitable conjugate of these subgroups, one can make the intersection being a lattice of $\operatorname{SO}(2,1)$.

Comment: What did you try? Did you think about that case $G=SL(2,R)$?

Comment: OK, now try to construct a counterexample to your conjecture using lattices in $SL(2,R)$.

Comment: I tried with arithmetic lattices of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ via quaternion algebras, wether they have the same invariant trace field or not. I don’t know how to describe non-arithmetic lattices. I wonder if the  question has an affirmative answer when we restrict to arithmetic lattices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are asking two different questions:

1. In the OP: Suppose that $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2< G$ are lattices and $\Gamma_1\cap \Gamma_2$ is Zariski dense in $G$. Does it follow that $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ are commensurable?

Counter-examples exist among lattices (say, one is arithmetic and the other is not) in $G=O(n,1)$ for all $n\ge 2$, see

*Gromov, M.; Piatetski-Shapiro, Ilya I.*, [**Non-arithmetic groups in Lobachevsky spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02698928), Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 66, 93-103 (1988). [ZBL0649.22007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0649.22007).

You can find pdf file [here](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/759.pdf). Examples are much easier to construct for $n=2$.

2. In comments: Suppose that $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2< G$ are arithmetic lattices in a reductive Lie group and $\Gamma_1\cap \Gamma_2$ is Zariski dense in $G$. Does it follow that $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ are commensurable? The positive answer is given in 1.6 (**Commensurability Criterion**) of the same paper.